# Options for EC2 ec2-create-snapshot and family

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am trying to use the various tools provided by ec2-ami-tools

Eg,

```
ec2-create-snapshot -h 

....



     -K, --private-key KEY
          Specify KEY as the private key to use. Defaults to the value of the
          EC2_PRIVATE_KEY environment variable (if set). Overrides the default.

     -C, --cert CERT
          Specify CERT as the X509 certificate to use. Defaults to the value 
          of the EC2_CERT environment variable (if set). Overrides the default.
```

-K and -C are two required values, and I cant understand what values are these expecting?

If I create a Keypair from Elasticfox, I get only one file to download and a fingerprint. So which of this need to get where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -C and -K values need the [X.509 certficate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) and private key that you've generated for your EC2 account; there are more details at [this link on the AWS site](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSecurityCredentials/1.0/AboutAWSCredentials.html#X509Credentials).  You can have AWS create these files if you don't have them already, or create new ones (recommended practice is to change your X.509 certificate every 90 days).

To create a new certificate and private key through AWS, go to your account details on the [AWS site](http://aws.amazon.com), click the Security Credentials link and then select the X.509 Certificates tab under Access Credentials.